# Regex jQuery - trim end character (trailing slash)

Tags: jquery, regex

Recently, we redirected any non-trailing slash URL's to trailing slash ones (/). I am working on this project. Lets call it: https://thisisatest.com/about-us/

We used this script to insert the page title as class on the body for styling purposes:

```
if (pageTitle != "") {
            if (pageTitle.indexOf('/') > -1) {
                pageTitle = pageTitle.replace(/\//g, "-");
            }
            $("body").addClass(pageTitle);
        }`
```

I need help removing the last "-" because of this script, the class inserts "-" at the end due to having "/" at the very last. `<body class="full-width about-us-">`

How can I remove the last "-" so it will just be `<body class="full-width about-us">`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace with regex to remove the last '-'. The `$` sign means end of line for regex.

```
if (pageTitle != "") {
    if (pageTitle.indexOf('/') > -1) {
        pageTitle = pageTitle.replace(/\//g, "-");
        pageTitle = pageTitle.replace(/-$/, ""); // remove last dash
    }
    $("body").addClass(pageTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some better solution but the quick solution I see is to use `lastIndexOf()` instead of `indexOf()` to find out an index of last dash (-) and substring it.